# C - How do I make this null statement work?

Tags: c, null, character, charactercount

I am following "The C Programming Language. 2nd Edition", and have got up to "1.5.2 Character Counting".

The code provided for a character counter that uses a null statement is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    double nc;
    for(nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc)
        ;
    printf("%.0f\n", nc);
}
```

Yet the program does not output the number of characters of the input:

```
input
input
```

Whereas if I included curly brackets and ignored the null statement:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    double nc;
    for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc) {
        printf("%.0f\n", nc);
    }
}
```

...it provides the correct output:

```
input
0
1
2
3
4
5
input
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

How do I make the null statement version of the program work?

Comment: You need to type `<Enter><Ctrl+D>` (Un*x) or `<Enter><Ctrl+Z>` (Windows) to signal end of input (`EOF`) to the program, otherwise it stays "stuck" at the `getchar()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have plenty of issues in your code, but none of them is related to the empty statement:

1. `main` type and arguments are wrong
2. Pressing ENTER does not close the `stdin` and function will not return EOF.

Check for EOF **and** new line.

```
int main(void) {
    int nc,ch;
    for(nc = 0; (ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n'; ++nc)
        ;
    printf("%d\n", nc);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Yc1c3K

Comment: This works in the Compiler Explorer, but not when I run it on Visual Studio - if I type something and press enter, it merely closes the window, saying it has exited with "code 0".

Comment: add `while(1);` after the print.

Comment: It works the same good. You simply do not see it as console window is closed instantly after the program exits. Joy of windows. But you need to try to work it out yourself. If you do not, you will never learn how to sort out the problems.